# PHP variable and function name

Tags: php

I need to create function in `php` which can take some variable to make function name full. For example:

```
    $variable = 'edit';

    function notifications($variable){
      // here i want to call for example function 'edit_something()
     $this-> $variable . _something(); // Here the function must be edit_something();
    }
```

I have an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _something()

Please help.

Comment: Take the () brackets out of the string, and call it like: $this->$name()

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Sorry...my mistake. It's not '_something()... It's like this:
$this->activity_feed_lib->$activity . _edit($account, $project, $milestone, $task);

Comment: Did you try using `eval`? Like: `eval (sprintf('$this->activity_feed_lib->%s_edit()', $variable));` would call `$this->activity_feed_lib->hello_edit()` if `$variable = 'hello';`